# Constraint not working within XML XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

To cut a long story short, i´m fighting to get a key keyref constrain working by using xsd.

My entry XML look like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<article-catalog  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
     xmlns="https://namespace.xyz.com"
            xsi:schemaLocation="https://namespace.xyz.com article-catalog.xsd">
 <categories>
  <category category-id="V">
   <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
   <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description>  
   <category category-id="V4">
    <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
    <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description>
    <category category-id="V4D">
     <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
     <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description>    
    </category>   
    <category category-id="V4I">
     <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
     <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description>    
    </category> 
   </category>  
  </category>
  <category category-id="G">
   <short-description language="de">ShortName</short-description>
   <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description>  
   <category category-id="GD">
    <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
    <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description>
    <category category-id="GDY">
     <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
     <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description>    
    </category>   
   </category>  
  </category>
 </categories>
 
 <articles>
  <article article-id="a1">
   <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
   <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description> 
   <price>68.80</price>
   <categories>
    <category ref-category-id="V4D" visible="false"/>
    <category ref-category-id="GDYX" visible="true"/>
   </categories>
   <advantageous-spots>
    <advantageous-spot order-id="1" language="de">Punkt 1</advantageous-spot>
    <advantageous-spot order-id="2" language="de">Punkt 2</advantageous-spot>
   </advantageous-spots>   
  </article>
  <article article-id="a2" ref-article-id="a1">
   <short-description language="de">Short Name</short-description>
   <long-description language="de">Long Name</long-description> 
   <price>68.80</price>
   <categories>
    <category ref-category-id="V4D" visible="false"/>
    <category ref-category-id="GDY" visible="true"/>
   </categories>
   <advantageous-spots>
    <advantageous-spot order-id="1" language="de">Punkt 1</advantageous-spot>
    <advantageous-spot order-id="2" language="de">Punkt 2</advantageous-spot>
   </advantageous-spots>   
  </article>
 </articles> 
</article-catalog>
```

I would like to set up a reference between

category-id and ref-categories-id by using this XSD

My first reference between article-id and ref-article-id is working quit well.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="https://namespace.xyz.com"
   targetNamespace="https://namespace.xyz.com"
   attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
   elementFormDefault="qualified" 
   xmlns:tns="https://namespace.xyz.com">


 <xs:element name="article-catalog" type="defArticleCatalog">
<!-- 
 Define unique key for article number
 -->
  <xs:unique     name="keyArticleID">
   <xs:selector xpath="*/tns:article" />
   <xs:field    xpath="@article-id" />
  </xs:unique>   
<!-- 
 Define unique key for category id
-->
  <xs:unique     name="keyCategoryID">
   <xs:selector xpath="*/tns:category|*/*/tns:category|*/*/*/tns:category" />
   <xs:field    xpath="@category-id" />
  </xs:unique>   
<!-- 
 Define referernce between detail and master article
-->
  <xs:keyref name="refArticleID" refer="keyArticleID">
     <xs:selector xpath="*/tns:article"/>
     <xs:field xpath="@ref-article-id"/>
  </xs:keyref>   
<!-- 
 Define referernce between article and category 
-->
  <xs:keyref name="refCategorieID" refer="keyCategoryID">
     <xs:selector xpath="*/tns:article/tns:categories/tns:category"/>
     <xs:field xpath="@ref-category-id"/>
  </xs:keyref>   
 </xs:element> 

 <xs:complexType name="defArticleCatalog">
         <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="categories" type="defCategories" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         <xs:element name="articles" type="defArticles" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
         </xs:sequence>

 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="defCategories">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="category" type="defCategory1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence> 
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="defCategory1">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="short-description" type="defText"/>
   <xs:element name="long-description" type="defText"/>
   <xs:element name="category" type="defCategory2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="category-id" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>  

 <xs:complexType name="defCategory2">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="short-description" type="defText"/>
   <xs:element name="long-description" type="defText"/>
   <xs:element name="category" type="defCategory3" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="category-id" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>  

 <xs:complexType name="defCategory3">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="short-description" type="defText"/>
   <xs:element name="long-description" type="defText"/>
     </xs:sequence>
     <xs:attribute name="category-id" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>  

 <xs:complexType name="defText" mixed="true">
  <xs:attribute name="language" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="defArticles">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="article" type="defArticle" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>  
     
 <xs:complexType name="defArticle">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="short-description" type="defText"/>
   <xs:element name="long-description" type="defText"/>
          <xs:element name="price" type="xs:float"/>
   <xs:element name="categories" type="defCategoriesRef"/>
   <xs:element name="advantageous-spots" type="defAdvantageousSpots" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>          
  </xs:sequence> 
  <xs:attribute name="article-id" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="ref-article-id"  type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="defCategoriesRef">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="category" type="defCategoryRef" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>          
  </xs:sequence> 
 </xs:complexType>
 
 <xs:complexType name="defCategoryRef" mixed="true">
  <xs:attribute name="ref-category-id" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:attribute name="visible" use="required" type="xs:boolean"/>
 </xs:complexType> 
  
 <xs:complexType name="defAdvantageousSpots">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="advantageous-spot" type="defAdvantageousSpot" maxOccurs="10"/>          
  </xs:sequence> 
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="defAdvantageousSpot" mixed="true">
  <xs:attribute name="order-id" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:attribute name="language" use="required" type="xs:string"/>
 </xs:complexType>  
  
</xs:schema>
```

unfortunatly I had no luck and I did not find the problem. Perhaps someone could give me a hint ;-)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, which one?

Comment: Sorry I forget to post the error message  
cvc-identity-constraint.4.3: Key 'refCategorieID' with value 'V4D' not found for identity constraint of element 'article-catalog'. article-catalog.xml /ReimoXML line 65 XML Problem